# Weight / items that a particular person carries

Tags: single-word-requests

If a person has multiple items carried with them, how can these items be referred as one thing?

> The total weight of his _______ was 20kg and it consisted of 2 rucksacks, umbrella and a water bottle.

Comment: 'Belongings' might be suitable, depending on your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [luggage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/luggage) may fit here:

> - the bags, suitcases, etc. that contain your possessions and that you take with you when you are travelling.

or, a more generic term is:

[belongings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/belongings), often *personal belongings*:

> - the things that a person owns, especially those that can be carried.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

**Burden**

> something that is carried : load

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burden)

Answer (score 0):

**Kit**, as in "kitted out."  More common in BrE than AmE.

https://www.google.com/search?q=define+kit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

**kit out**.

> phrasal verb [usually passive] If someone or something is kitted out,
>   they have everything they need at a particular time, such as clothing,
>   equipment, or furniture. [British, informal] Kit out definition and
>   meaning | Collins English Dictionary
>   https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/kit-out